# Google references subfolders

Tags: google, search-engine-indexing, google-index

Last week I launched a website and created a `robots.txt`:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
Sitemap: http://mywebsite.tld/sitemap_robots.xml
```

Now I've checked the indexed pages (`Google -> site:mywebsite.tld`) and found links to subfolders and non-public/internal files, that are place outside of the web root of the website. E.g.: `mywebsite.tld/vendor/`, `mywebsite.tld/module/`, `mywebsite.tld`, `mywebsite.tld/dev/`, `mywebsite.tld/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/tests/ZendTest/Test/PHPUnit` etc.

Why are such folders being indexed? Why is it possible, if they are placed outside of the website root and there are not links to them? How to avoid indexing of such paths?

---

EDIT

The folder structure of my website is:

```
/composer.json
/composer.lock
/composer.phar
/config/
/data/
/dev/
/init_autoloader.php
/LICENSE.txt
/module/
/public/ <-- web root
/README.md
/temp/
/vendor/
```

It's a common structure of a Zend Framework 2 project (with some additional folders). The document root is the folder `public` (set in Plesk):

[image: mywebsite-web-root]

Comment: What do you mean by "outside the web root"? The URLs like `mywebsite.tld/module/` are definitely not valid, and return a 404, right?

Comment: Exactly. Please see my question update.

Answer (score 2):

In order to block all robots in your website, the correct code is:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Don't forget the `/` (slash) after `Disallow:`.

To block only subdirectories and their internal webpages with *robots.txt*, you have to list them one by one. Thus you need to know their names:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /vendor/
Disallow: /module/
...
```

To understand how *robots.txt* works, you can read [this](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449) or [this](http://www.robotstxt.org/).

---

Moreover, for your information, when you buy a domain name, several websites are notified and put links to your website even if you don't want to. That's why, you need to block all robots if you don't want to see your webpages being indexed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Don't Disallow: / mean `Don't index any page of the website at all`? It's not, what I want. I only want, that my "internal" folders are not being indexed.

Comment: I have edited my answer.

Comment: `/` stays for webroot. Right? The _webroot_ of my project is a subfolder `public` of the project root folder (`/var/www/.../projectfolder/public`). `Disallow: /vendor/` would mean "Exclude /var/www/.../projectfolder/public/vendor/". But there is no folder `vendor` in the `public` folder. The folders `vendor`, `module` etc. are placed _outside_ of the webroot.

Comment: Don't think about folders in your server but URL. If you want to block `website.tld/vendor/`, you need to put the following line in your _robots.txt_: `Disallow: /vendor/`.

Comment: OK. But what is `/`? It's obviously not the webroot.

Comment: `/` refers to the entire website (directories, webpages, images...)

Comment: What is the "entire website" from the technical view? I mean, **how** (in a case like mine, when the web root doesn't equal to the project root) **does the search engine, e.g. Google, know, where the website/project root is?** And how cat it find the folders outside of the web root, if there are no links to them?

Comment: I think you misunderstand one thing. Google robots only see URL structure and don't see your technical folders (on your server). There is only your web server (Apache or Nginx for example) which knows your folders and URL structure and in general, it rewrites URL structure to point on good technical folder. The _entire website_ refers to all URL Google robots can find.

Comment: It's logical, I can understand it. And it's also my point. I just cannot find an explanation, why Google indexes the folder _outside_ of the document root.

Comment: Ok. In that case, Google indexes your folder because robots find a link. It's the only explanation. Google can't imagine your server folders structure.

Comment: You are right. Some time long here actually have been exiting links to these folders. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I've finally found a plausible explanation, why Google has indexed folders and files outside of the document root:

[image: google-search-site-results-item]

The website I've launched last week is a second version of a project. The first version was Joomla! based and its dosument root was to the project root:

> /var/www/.../mywebsite.tld

The second version bases on Zend Framework 2 and uses its common project structure. So the web root is

> /var/www/.../mywebsite.tld/public

We had some technical troubles. So the initial deploy of the second version took several days and only at the last day the document root of the website has been changed to `.../public`. During all this time the index page was looking like this:

[image: mywebsite-with-wrong-root]

So the Google bot indexed all these links, that are broken now, but was returning status `200` some days ago.